# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header issue with hapijs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, cors, hapi.js

Hi i have a problem with my facebook app. When i start it after the authentcation it gives me this error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http: //localhost:8000/informations. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: //localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
>   :8080/carRandomizer:1
>
> > XMLHttpRequest cannot load http: //localhost:8000/rand. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: //localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

So i understand that is a CORS problem, i already tryed to follow the official docs http://hapijs.com/api#serverrouteoptions and now i set on my server.js file this:

> server.connection({
>     port: process.env.PORT,
>     routes: {
>       cors: true
>     }
>   });

and now i have the same error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https: //www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=1463042613952341&respo…k&state=URaCt6cXqf_JzJYgS9KlwM&scope=public_profile%2Cuser_friends%2Cemail. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>   angular.js:12330 (anonymous function) @ angular.js:12330(anonymous function) @ app.js:817(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14567a.$get.n.$eval @ angular.js:15846a.$get.n.$digest @ angular.js:15657a.$get.n.$apply @ angular.js:15951l @ angular.js:10364F @ angular.js:10536e @ angular.js:10487
>   :8080/carRandomizer:1 
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https: //www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=1463042613952341&respo…k&state=j-vSbeB6rGvEi_cgu-9TrM&scope=public_profile%2Cuser_friends%2Cemail. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

finally i also tryed to set the hanlder for the

http: //localhost:8000/rand

the response header this but nothing changes.

Comment: I have same problem. Could you solve it?

Comment: @Alex not yet sorry.

Comment: my problem disappeared after trying some variations - but ending up with the EXACT SAME code !!!??? I hat miracles

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying `origin: ['*']` in the route configuration:

```
server.connection({ port: process.env.PORT, routes: { cors: { origin: ['*'] } } });
```

It looks like hapi is not picking up your connection options.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, i have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

your server-side may have a white list includes all the domains
maybe you need to add your domain into the white list of server-side's cors.
thanks.